# Split string after specific character or after max length

Tags: c#, string, split

i want to split a string the following way:

```
string s = "012345678x0123x01234567890123456789";
s.SplitString("x",10);
```

should be split into

```
012345678
x0123
x012345678
9012345678
9
```

e.g. the inputstring should be split after the character "x" or length 10 - what comes first.

here is what i've tried so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitString(this string sInput, string search, int maxlength)
{
    int index = Math.Min(sInput.IndexOf(search), maxlength);
    int start = 0;
    while (index != -1)
    {
        yield return sInput.Substring(start, index-start);
        start = index;
        index = Math.Min(sInput.IndexOf(search,start), maxlength);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the output you currently get

Comment: Please add info about the problem you met, not clear right now

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't you update the start parameter after every substring call?

Comment: You have to use the overload of `IndexOf` with the start index in the loop: `sInput.IndexOf(search, start)`. Otherwise you're always searching from the beginning.

Comment: @Tim / Zohar - updated, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't like RegEx. It creates code that is hard to de-bug and is very hard to work out what it is meant to be doing when you first look at it. So for a more lengthy solution I would go with something like this.

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitString(this string sInput, char search, int maxlength)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var count = 0;
        var lastSplit = 0;

        foreach (char c in sInput)
        {
            if (c == search || count - lastSplit == maxlength)
            {
                result.Add(sInput.Substring(lastSplit, count - lastSplit));
                lastSplit = count;
            }

            count ++;
        }

        result.Add(sInput.Substring(lastSplit, count - lastSplit));

        return result;
    }
```

Note I changed the first parameter to a char (from a string). This code can probably be optimised some more, but it is nice and readable, which for me is more important.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with this regular expression:

```
([^x]{1,10})|(x[^x]{1,9})
```

which means:

> Match at most 10 characters that are not `x` OR match `x` followed by at most 9 characters thar are not `x`

Here is working example:

```
string regex = "([^x]{1,10})|(x[^x]{1,9})";
string input = "012345678x0123x01234567890123456789";
var results = Regex.Matches(input, regex)
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Value);
```

which produces values by you.

Comment: with this solution it's a bit tricky to set the seperator / maxlength-parameter dynamically and i'm not sure about the performance with very long input-strings

Comment: @fubo, is it? You just create different string representing regular expression, replacing `x` with other separator, `10` and `9` with maxlength and maxlength - 1...

Comment: with the inputstring from the example, Mike's solution takes 760 Ticks of time, the regex takes 35400 ticks